# ANGULAR Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content

Tags: angular, youtube-api

I am embedding the YOUTUBE video in my ANGULAR app.

For that, I had performed the NPM INSTALL @angular/youtube-player.

Added code in APP.MODULE

```
  imports: [
    YouTubePlayerModule,
```

And then run the page it shows me the below error.

```
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-j6Tt8qv7z2kSc7fUs0YHbrxawwsQcS05fVaX1r2qrbk='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes, and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

[image]
in my **INDEX.HTML** page placed the below code but still not working.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>PROJECT NAME</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <!-- <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="upgrade-insecure-requests"
    /> -->
     <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'none'; 
      script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; img-src 'self';
      connect-src 'self' ws://localhost:4200; font-src 'self';"
    /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2" />
    <!-- <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="upgrade-insecure-requests"
    /> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <noscript
      >Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript
    >
  </body>
</html>
```

HERE IS PACKAGE.json infor

```
    "@angular/animations": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/youtube-player": "^14.2.6",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

in my **style.css** page

```
@import url(https://bootswatch.com/5/quartz/bootstrap.min.css);
```

Comment: Well, it fails to compile - most probably due to using `youtube-player` version `14.2.6` with angular 12. In angular ecosystem, usually you want to align the major versions (at the very least) of your libraries. Downgrade `youtube-player` to something with major version 12, e.g. `12.2.13`, which seems to be current LTS version.

Comment: @TotallyNewb TRIED but still not working